# How to add an oval at top-right of an ImageView?

Tags: xml, imageview

I'm looking for set an oval(XML) at the top-right of an ImageView for example something like this:

```
--------------
           O | <----- oval made by xml
             |
             |
  Imageview  |
             |
_____________|
```

I have many Imageviews added on a gridview with an Adapter, It could be possible? If it couldn't, give me some ideas please, Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Just added on `XML`: an icon (made in XML, `<shape ...>`) at `top|right` of an `ImageView`, and make use of his `android:id` to make whatever you want on Activity, finally I set up a function who gives some information about the `ImageView` when I click over there